# Gracefully handling DB Node reboot in J2EE application

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, database-connection, connection-pooling

In my organization, Oracle database is a 2 node RAC database.  Each member of the cluster is on a reboot schedule that is:

Node 1 - First Sunday of each month at 1:00am
Node 2 - Second Sunday of each month at 1:00am

Whenever these node gets rebooted, I see below exception in my J2EE application log file:

```
org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.rollback(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:209)
... 154 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: ORA-01089: immediate shutdown in progress - no operations are permitted

                    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
                    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:389)
                    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:382)
                    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C7Ocommoncall.processError(T4C7Ocommoncall.java:93)
                    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive
```

Our  DBAs said that "**We do a shutdown transactional local.  It is supposed to try to wait for in flight transactions to finish and not allow new transactions.** "

As I mentioned above, out of 2 nodes, only one node gets rebooted at a time, and considering DBAs answer.. our app should never block on database during reboot process.

My question is, why my application is throwing this exception then? And why my application is trying to connect to a DB node for which shut down is in progress?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application isn't trying to connect to a node that is shutting down.  It's already connected when the shutdown starts.

I assume that your application maintains a connection pool in the middle tier.  So, presumably, just before one of the nodes restarts, your connection pool has open connections to both nodes.  When the DBA does a `shutdown transactional`, sessions that have active transactions are allowed to complete but most of the sessions in your connection pool that are connected to the node that is shutting down will not have active transactions at that point.  When you get one of these connections from the connection pool and try to start a transaction, you'll get this error.

Most likely, you want to catch this error and reconnect which should cause a new connection to be made to the remaining node.  The error you're getting is a `SQLRecoverableException` so it would generally make sense to try to recover.